# Coinbase API getSpotPrice not returning historic prices

Tags: node.js, coinbase-api

Like the title says, when I add a date parameter to the getSpotPrice function, it does not return the historic price that corresponds with that day, instead, it returns the current price. Can anybody show me a short snippet of code that does this properly? so I might compare the code snippets. 
The date.yyyymmdd function returns the date string like this: "2017-07-17"
Any Ideas?

```
moneyBot.client.getSpotPrice({
    'date': date.yyyymmdd(),
    'currency': "USD"

}, function (err, price) {

    console.log(price.data.amount.yellow);
    console.log(date.yyyymmdd().white);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in previous version of coinbase-node module. In 2.0.7 it works.